# How to tell vim to ignore commands type error and do not drop into insert mode

Tags: vim, youcompleteme

I use vim with [Youcompleteme](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe).

I set some key maps in .vimrc, for example:

```
let mapleader=','
nmap <leader>imp :YcmCompleter GoToImplementation<CR>
```

My whole .vimrc is [here](https://pastebin.com/1J2MCbmY), it's a bit of messy.

sometimes I mistype ",imp" to ",im", or other mistypes. And vim behaves strange. I uploaded an ascii recording [here](https://asciinema.org/a/ICo3S3YrhQwvhnDsoUeV08ups).

My question is how to tell vim to ignore commands if not matched against any key maps I set in .vimrc?

Comment: The solution to "I make typos" is to stop making typos.

Answer (score 0):

You can map any common undesired lead-ins to do nothing:

```
nnoremap ,imp :YcmCompleter GoToImplementation<CR>
nnoremap ,im <esc>
```

You can obviously not map any mistypo to be ignored. You would for instance still like `imp` to insert `mp`

Comment: I considered about this approach, I have a few keys mapped, going this way I would have to add many lines, and problem still exists: if I map "i", "im", "imp", then if I typed "inp", or "i2p", it would still cause problem, I want to ignore all un-mapped keys.


edit: sorry I pressed enter to get a new line but on SO it auto save comment.